# Is it possible to have responsive images with CSS background images using Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, background-image, responsive, drupal-8, responsive-images

I know it's possible to use responsive images in Drupal 8. So for different screen sizes you get different images (which is interesting for the performance, cause I don't want a very large image on my mobile phone).

But now I wonder if you can do that with background images inside Drupal 8? So I want to be able to upload an image in Drupal 8 that is a responsive image (different screen sizes => different images) but for a background image. Anybody has any experience in that area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would still use responsive images to configure it all within the CMS, then use a page preprocess hook to get the information out of the responsive image field and stored into a JSON object spat out into the page .

Then the last piece of the puzzle would be to write my own javascript which checks for onload and onresize events and sets the background image based on the information stored in the json object.

Comment: There appears to be a contrib module which supports this, but it's not one I've used before so can't vouch for it. https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter

Comment: Hi @Fool, thank you for your response. I follow you that it would be possible to still use the responsive images inside Drupal but the last piece you've said about to check with javascript onload or onresize I wouldn't do. To me it looks kinda like overkill and not the best way performance wise. Now I don't know another option either.

Regarding the contrib module bg_image_formatter I've tested this but doesn't do the necessary.

Thanks for reaching out!

Answer (score 0):

In which context do you want to do this? is it a content type or a custom block? would you have a custom template for this?

In that case, supposing you have fields on your entity for each image size, you could put inline style in the tpl twig file and get the values for the images from the database. Not the prettiest but I don't think you can skip the `<style>` tag implementation while trying to implement any css from db without js.

Comment: thank you for your response. The context doesn't really matter, just want to find a good working solution. I understand that doing this the custom way like you explain could work but the workload seems quite large (or am I wrong)? Especially if you know that responsive images with a normal image can be done quite fast just by Drupal configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is now the [Responsive Background Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_background_image) module for Drupal 8. It's currently at an alpha release and I haven't tested it, but am planning to as I have the same need.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: @plousia thanks for the the reference link I will have a look at that. Also if you have a working example or have tested this please let know what you think of it. Thanks!

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur thanks for the notification. In this case, the link is pretty much the only answer I have. Nick, I'm afraid I haven't got a working example yet, am planning to test it out next week.